# Why is the Output of these Two Lists Different?

Tags: python, list, printing, append

```
import random

words = ['nugget', 'jasmine', 'trolley', 'weight', 'soap']
mywords = []

random.shuffle(words)
mywords.append(random.sample(words, 2))

print("Words: ")
for i in words:
    print(str(i))

print("My Words: ")
for i in mywords:
    print(str(i))
```

I am working on an example that moves items from one list to another. The example seems to work as intended except for the output of the second list 'mywords', which prints in brackets and not as an unordered list as the list 'words' prints. Any suggestions? My guess is it has something to do with the append function I used.

Comment: What would you expect exactly, what do you get? Don't paraphrase output - what is *"which prints in brackets and not as an unordered list as the list 'words'"*?

Comment: expected output example: Words: 
nugget
jasmine
soap
trolley
weight
My Words: 
trolley
nugget

Comment: actual output example: Words: 
weight
trolley
nugget
soap
jasmine
My Words: 
['soap', 'nugget']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `random.sample()` returns a list. The function `list.append()` takes the item you pass as an arugment, in this case a `list`, and adds it to the end of your list. If you replace `append()` with `extend()` it will add each item returned from `random.sample()` to the list individually.

Comment: Thank you. Using Extend instead of Append solved the problem.

Comment: I will read more about those functions

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample(words,2)` creates a list of 2 words that are then appended as the only element of mywords. I suggest you might want to use `mywords = random.sample(words, 2)` instead.